# Can anyone modify this code so that it can be used for classes because if I write getElementsByClassName the code doesn't work so plese help me

Tags: javascript, html, web, copy, clipboard

```
<script>
function copyClipboard() {
  var elm = document.getElementById("divClipboard");
  // for Internet Explorer

  if(document.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(elm);
    range.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("Copied div content to clipboard");
  }
  else if(window.getSelection) {
    // other browsers

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(elm);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("Copied div content to clipboard");
  }
}
</script>
```

Plese modify this code so that it can be used for classes rather then for id. If I change "getElementById" to "getElementsByClassName" the code doesn't work. So please help .

Comment: Please attach the HTML code that we can investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements where all the elements have the same class. So if there's only one element of class "divClipboard", you can change that line to,

```
var elm = document.getElementsByClassName("divClipboard")[0];
```